# status and error fields in the table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, error-handling, status

I am trying to think of good table design for defining statuses and error if any.

For example in the `queue` table I am considering creating two fields called `status` and `error`.

By default `error` value would be null.

The value in `status` field could be one of the following: pending, in_queue, completed, error

If I define error value in the `status` field - it doesn't tell me what type of error it is.  Should I set error value in the `status` and in the `error` to describe error type such as: ftp_login_failed

eg:

```
update queue set status='error' error='ftp_login_failed' where id=5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with:

- Either only one field, `status` which can be pending, in_queue, completed, error_a, error_b, ...  If you select your error names wisely, you can do `SELECT ... WHERE status LIKE 'error%'`
- Or two fields, where `status` can be pending, in_queue and completed, and then if completed then `error IS NULL` means no error, while `error IS NOT NULL` means that there was an error.

Comment: on the second option - you wouldn't change `status` to error value if `error IS NOT NULL`. Just keep the state of status